# Is there a dial from Addres Book and tel:/sip: protocol handler script/application available for 10.7?

Tags: applescript, script, contacts

We are currently using Mac OS X 10.6 and **snomURLHandler** to convert tel: uri's to a http GET request. This computer telephony integration let us click on a telephone number in Address Book.app and let our desktop phone dial the number.

As snomURLHandler version 1.0 by Alastair J. Houghton (2004) is compiled to **PowerPC** code, and the Rosetta component to run PowerPC code is no longer available in 10.7 (Lion), this situation is blocking upgrade to 10.7 (Lion).

What alternatives are available for snomURLHandler, preferrably a **script or application** that can be used as a general **tel: and sip: protocol handler** (to call links starting with tel: and sip: from a web browser) and also be used from Address Book.app?

Note: We are aware of Telify add-on. That is not what is asked for, as Telify only works in one browser (Firefox) and cannot be used from Address Book.app

Comment: You may get more appropriate visibility for your problem on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Have you tried posting there?

Comment: @ephsmith Have tried superuser once with a Mac question, that was immediately being redirected back to apple.stackexchange.com because it was Mac OX related.

Comment: sorry to hear that.  It was just a thought. I wasn't trying to redirect.

Comment: @ephsmith Your "redirection" was read as helpfulness, and is being appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code of snomURLHandler is available at http://alastairs-place.net/hg/snomURLHandler/file/eb798e1a6dc8

Download that source code and compile this to an application using Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [DefaultApps prefpane](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to specify custom URL handling, along with a lot of other features.

It hasn't been updated in quite awhile, but works fine on 10.6.8 and I believe on 10.7.4.

Comment: We are looking for the converter, from "tel: and sip:" to "http://". We are not looking for a mechanism to configure it in the OS.

Comment: What's the functional difference of using a "script or application" versus creating a system-wide hook?  Do you need to only allow tel:/sip: requests to be redirected to http: from one specific application instead of system-wide (which seems unlikely)?

Comment: The difference is that some data format conversion needs to be done. For example `tel:+1987654321` should be converted `http://192.168.0.1/command.htm?number=000011987654321&outgoing_uri=123@domain1` plus some http authentication headers need to be created.

Comment: Should've included that in your original post.